# Apps Marketplace SDK: Test Install Flow button missing

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Am creating a new project to migrate an oauth1 app to oauth2.  Have enabled (and configured) the Apps Marketplace SDK.  I am not seeing a "Test Install Flow" button in the settings screen.

I have not found any clues, after much searching, regarding prerequisites for making the button appear in the interface.  Can anyone provide pointers about what to check for / what prerequisites I may have missed?

Update:  I added an additional scope (beside userinfo.profile and userinfo.email) and the button appeared several minutes after saving the change.  So problem solved, I suppose.  Hope this helps the next person down the line :)

Update:  I made a change to Universal Navigation Extension URL - and Test Install Flow button has again turned off.  Reverted to the previous URL, and still no button.  Is there some sort of an undocumented propagation period?

Comment: You should add an answer to your own question. I believe that's the best way to indicate you've solved your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible that the solution here works for you - ["Integrate with Google" button disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472084/integrate-with-google-button-disappeared)

In the marketplace SDK settings, uncheck the "Enable individual installs" option. The option doesn't do anything at the moment and shouldn't be enabled.