# "Integrate with Google" button disappeared

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

[image]

This is the listing of our Google Apps Marketplace app. The button has also disappeared from every page we've put the integration on.

When I'm looking at the console log in the browser on pages where the button should be appearing, I see that calls to this url: `https://apis.google.com/additnow/additnow.html?...` result in this error:

```
Forbidden

Error 403
```

This is the link to our Marketplace listing: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-signature-marketing/iopfifjpbcpfjpfaphafndgmjlmboejd

**It's impossible to install the product at the moment**, what might be the issue?

Comment: Interesting.  Checking the console for my issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457728/apps-marketplace-sdk-test-install-flow-button-missing) also shows a 403 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the marketplace SDK settings, uncheck the "Enable individual installs" option. The option doesn't do anything at the moment and shouldn't be enabled.

**Update:** Preferred fix (assuming your app can/will support individual user installs) is to do as MeLight says in the comment and create a new client ID with the "web application" type.

Comment: If this doesn't work: Click the Google Apps Marketplace SDK gear wheel, then click the API Access tab on the left menu, and then Create another client ID and from the list pick Web application type

Comment: Hi Steve.  Will changing the "Enable individual installs" option require the Domain Admin to "Grant Data" Access again.  I have found that any small change to the Marketplace App results in any gadget dissapearing until the Permissions are re-granted.  For example changing the "Setup URL" killed the gadget for existing installations.  I don't want to have this change having the same effect.

Comment: Hi Steve, I've created a new thread which has the details of my experience with this issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578125/changing-anything-in-marketplace-sdk-requires-regrant-of-permissions