# Changing anything in Marketplace SDK requires regrant of permissions

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am running into a recurring issue with the Marketplace Listing/SDK.

Anytime something minor is changed, the Contextual gadget disappears from the clients Gmail.

When we look at the Marketplace App in the clients Google Apps Admin everything is fine.

However if we go to "Data Access" and revoke permission and re-grant it, fairly soon the gadget will reappear.

This has to be done for any customer that has the App installed.

An example is fixing the issue described in the following link where we have to "check off" Enable individual Install.

["Integrate with Google" button disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472084/integrate-with-google-button-disappeared)

Google has made a change that means we need to adjust our settings and this whole "regrant" process is initiated.

Is this a bug or an undocumented feature?  has anybody else encountered this???

Thanks for your input,

Paul C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a known bug. We hope to have the fix in production next week.

Comment: Thanks Eric - is there anywhere that bugs such as this can be tracked - this is a major for anybody with gadgets in production.

Comment: The fix was pushed last night, can you test again? We don't have bug tracking setup for the Apps Marketplace at the moment, but it's something we are working on.

Comment: Hi Eric - I made some changes and the gadget has not disappeared - so the issue I was experiencing seems to be fixed.  Thanks for following this up for me.